# Firefox specific CSS bug related to margins and img sizing

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have tested my site in IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera, and Firefox is the only one presenting this issue.

[image]
[image]

As you can see, the disclaimer's positioning is messed up, as well as the image's position and height.

After the full screen break the majority of the issues go away but the left/right margin still isn't right. There's no different in .top-opt-in and the only other difference is on the button; it switches from display: block to display: inline at the first break.

```
<div>
    <div class="top-opt-in-left"></div>
    <section class="top-opt-in center-block text-center">

        <div class="top-cta">
            ENTER YOUR EMAIL BELOW <span>to find out when Let's Do Lunch comes to you!</span>
        </div>
        <div class="top-opt-in-fields">
            <input class="email-field" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Enter Email Address" />                
            <img class="top-opt-in-button" id="top_submit"  />
            <label class="disclaimer">We hate spam as much as you! Unsubscribe anytime.</label>
        </div>

    </section>
</div>

.top-opt-in {    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position-x: center;
    position: relative;
}
/* Full Screen */
@media (min-width:1175px) {
    .top-opt-in {
        background-image: url(../images/top_optin_ribbon_full.png);
        height: 171px;
    }
}

.top-opt-in-button {
    /*display: block;*/
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
/* Full Screen */
@media (min-width:1175px) {
    .top-opt-in-button {
        background-image: url(../images/top_join_button_full.png);
        width: 212px;
        padding-left: 212px;
        height: 82px;
        display: inline;
        margin: auto auto;        
    }
}

.top-opt-in-fields label {
    display: block;
    font-family: FreeSans;
    color: #fffffd;
    font-size: 1em;
}
/* Full Screen */
@media (min-width:1175px) {
    .top-opt-in-fields label {
        margin-top: -1.75em;
        margin-left: -17.2em;
    }
}
```

Comment: whats the question? that's more of a statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to create a bunch of Firefox specific css rules but got this fully resolved. Incase anyone else runs into the issue here's how I was able to fix:

Put Firefox specific items inside of

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { }
```

Then tried a mixture of the following until able to remove any issues

1. .wrapper { position: relative; } .element { position: absolute; }
2. changing around margins until it looks right
3. Change display: inline; to display: inline-block;